# get all has_many associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationship

Let's say I have two models `Author` and `Book`, where Author `has_many :books` and Book `belongs_to :author`. Is there a way to get all books by all authors without iterating through all the authors using `each`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea, you can use `joins` or `includes`, if you want get all books, which have someone Author

```
Book.includes(:author)
```

if you want to get all books, you can simply:

```
Book.all
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `all` method.

```
Book.all
```

This will return all of the books on record.

Answer (score 0):

It will return all books wich have author and group it by author ID.

```
Book.joins(:author).group(:author_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

A word of caution about .all, it will literally make an instance for every Book.  If you have a large table this can be super expensive.

If you're doing this as a one off in the console and you already know the size of the table is reasonable you're okay.  I would strongly recommend against putting it in the application unless you know that the table will not grow.

If it's for a view, implement pagination.  If it's for a back end task, use batches http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html.